# How to identify subschemas with a URL URI in JSON Schema?

Tags: url, uri, jsonschema

[SPEC](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.8.2.4) provides next example how to identify schema:

```
{
    "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
    "definitions": {
        "B": {
            "$id": "other.json",
        },
    }
}

#/definitions/B   
        http://example.com/other.json
        http://example.com/other.json#
        http://example.com/root.json#/definitions/B
```

But how is it identified if root schema `root.json` would be defined under `/some/path` instead of `/` path?

```
{
    "$id": "http://example.com/some/path/root.json",
    "definitions": {
        "B": {
            "$id": "other.json",
        },
    }
}
```

How `other.json` should be identified?

```
http://example.com/other.json
```

or:

```
http://example.com/some/path/other.json
```

And which part of SPEC defines this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with your question please? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Relequestual: The SPEC provide example when `root.json` is defined under `/` path. What would be the right base `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com/some/path`  if `root.json` was defined under `/some/path` path?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear what you are asking. Can you modify your question to show a full example please? I don't understand what you mean by "defined under" because it's a little ambiguous.

Comment: @Relequestual: done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Schemas can be identified by any URI that has been given to them,
> including a JSON Pointer or their URI given directly by "$id". In all
> cases, dereferencing a "$ref" reference involves first resolving its
> value as a URI reference against the current base URI per RFC 3986
> [RFC3986].
> (Dereferencing section)[http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.8.3.2] of the spec.

The "base URI" is defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.1) which is referenced in the JSON Schema specification.

It's not super easy to understand because it's quite complex. In the case of a URL, where the reference to resolve is is a non hash fragment, **the base URI is is the URI parts before (but including) the last slash**.

(Note: JSON Schema defines that the value of an `$id` must be an absolute URI, without any fragments.)

**So to answer your question specifically `other.json` should be identified as `http://example.com/some/path/other.json`.**

You can see this in action if you try using the following schema in this [online JSON Schema validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)...

```
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/blah/root.json",
  "definitions": {
    "A": {
      "$id": "#foo"
    },
    "B": {
      "$id": "other.json",
      "definitions": {
        "X": {
          "$id": "#bar"
        },
        "Y": {
          "$id": "t/inner.json"
        }
      }
    },
    "C": {
      "$ref": "http://example.com/blah/other.json"
    }
  },
  "properties":{
    "a": { "$ref": "#/definitions/C" }
  }
}
```

In the `$ref` for "C", if you remove `/blah`, the validator will complain it can no longer resolve the reference.

Comment: Generally speaking, the base URI is the URI which URI references are resolved against. It's the same standard process used in HTML when you provide a reference in a link, it's resolved against the URI of the document it was found in. Use a library to resolve URI references, since it's not trivial.

Comment: @awwright The real question was, "where do I find the specification for URI reference resolution". As you said, it's not trivial, as I discovered when looking into the RFC!

Comment: Just a note on this you could do what i do with our server and use `DirectoryIndex root.json` rule in the directory `blah` that then means your id does not need to supply the root.json so then your C `$ref` can be `other.json`, check out https://api.thisisbeacon.com/schema/ and you can see it in action a complete tree setup i use as `DirectoryIndex schema.json` as it also works for all child directories

Comment: @MartinBarker You are assuming that example.com is even a network accessible URI, and that the server is connected to the internet, which may not be the case, and I'm not sure is relevant to the question. Let's discuss this on the JSON Schema Slack.